# Radial pie chart (with fixed width and height) won't align to horizontal & vertical centre

Tags: html, css

Despite setting properties, the text inside the circle won't move to the exact centre and the radial graph itself won't move to the centre of the div it is inside. Does anyone what's wrong and how to fix this?

```css
/**
 * Card Styles
 */

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  /* margin-bottom: 1.6rem; */
}

.card__padding {
  padding: 1.2rem;
}

.card__content {
  position: relative;
}


/* card article */

.card__article a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.card__article p {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}


/*radial progress bar*/

.pie-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.pie-wrapper .pie {
  clip: rect(0, 200px, 200px, 0px);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
}

.pie-wrapper .pie .half-circle {
  border: 10px solid #3498db;
  clip: rect(0, 100px, 200px, 0);
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.pie-wrapper .label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12.5%;
  right: 1%;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  color: black;
  cursor: default;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.pie-wrapper .shadow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 20px solid #bdc3c7;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.pie-wrapper.progress-full .pie {
  clip: inherit;
}

.pie-wrapper.progress-full .pie .right-side {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(220deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(220deg);
  transform: rotate(220deg);
}

div,
div:before,
div:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="card radius shadowDepth1">
  <div class="card__content card__padding">
    <article class="card__article">
      <h2><a href="#">Hello world</a></h2>
      <div class="pie-wrapper progress-full">
        <span class="label">2017</span>
        <div class="pie">
          <div class="left-side half-circle"></div>
          <div class="right-side half-circle"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>Bounjour, tout le monde</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `text-align: center;` to card class

```css
/**
 * Card Styles
 */

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  /* margin-bottom: 1.6rem; */
}

.card__padding {
  padding: 1.2rem;
}

.card__content {
  position: relative;
}


/* card article */

.card__article a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.card__article p {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}


/*radial progress bar*/

.pie-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.pie-wrapper .pie {
  clip: rect(0, 200px, 200px, 0px);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
}

.pie-wrapper .pie .half-circle {
  border: 10px solid #3498db;
  clip: rect(0, 100px, 200px, 0);
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.pie-wrapper .label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12.5%;
  right: 1%;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  color: black;
  cursor: default;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.pie-wrapper .shadow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 20px solid #bdc3c7;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.pie-wrapper.progress-full .pie {
  clip: inherit;
}

.pie-wrapper.progress-full .pie .right-side {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(220deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(220deg);
  transform: rotate(220deg);
}

div,
div:before,
div:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="card radius shadowDepth1">
  <div class="card__content card__padding">
    <article class="card__article">
      <h2><a href="#">Hello world</a></h2>
      <div class="pie-wrapper progress-full">
        <span class="label">2017</span>
        <div class="pie">
          <div class="left-side half-circle"></div>
          <div class="right-side half-circle"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>Bounjour, tout le monde</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.pie-wrapper .label {
     margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    right: auto;
    left: 2px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    color: black;
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

---

```
.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  /* margin-bottom: 1.6rem; */
  text-align:center;
}
```

---

```css
/**
 * Card Styles
 */

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  /* margin-bottom: 1.6rem; */
  text-align:center;
}

.card__padding {
  padding: 1.2rem;
}

.card__content {
  position: relative;
}


/* card article */

.card__article a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.card__article p {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}


/*radial progress bar*/

.pie-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.pie-wrapper .pie {
  clip: rect(0, 200px, 200px, 0px);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
}

.pie-wrapper .pie .half-circle {
  border: 10px solid #3498db;
  clip: rect(0, 100px, 200px, 0);
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.pie-wrapper .label {
     margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    right: auto;
    left: 2px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    color: black;
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.pie-wrapper .shadow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 20px solid #bdc3c7;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.pie-wrapper.progress-full .pie {
  clip: inherit;
}

.pie-wrapper.progress-full .pie .right-side {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(220deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(220deg);
  transform: rotate(220deg);
}

div,
div:before,
div:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="card radius shadowDepth1">
  <div class="card__content card__padding">
    <article class="card__article">
      <h2><a href="#">Hello world</a></h2>
      <div class="pie-wrapper progress-full">
        <span class="label">2017</span>
        <div class="pie">
          <div class="left-side half-circle"></div>
          <div class="right-side half-circle"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>Bounjour, tout le monde</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution involves the below CSS changes.

```
.card__article{
  text-align:center;
}

.pie-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
}

.pie-wrapper .label {
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  color: black;
  cursor: default;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 180px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

First you can just set `text-align:center` to center the contents. Second I positioned the text inside using `position:absolute` and made it take the full dimensions of the parent, by setting `top,right,bottom,left` to `0px`, then by setting the CSS property `line-height` to the inner height of the parent (excluding borders) `180px` we can center the contents!

```css
/**
 * Card Styles
 */

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  /* margin-bottom: 1.6rem; */
}

.card__padding {
  padding: 1.2rem;
}

.card__content {
  position: relative;
}


/* card article */

.card__article{
  text-align:center;
}

.card__article a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.card__article p {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}


/*radial progress bar*/

.pie-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
}

.pie-wrapper .pie {
  clip: rect(0, 200px, 200px, 0px);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
}

.pie-wrapper .pie .half-circle {
  border: 10px solid #3498db;
  clip: rect(0, 100px, 200px, 0);
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.pie-wrapper .label {
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  color: black;
  cursor: default;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 180px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.pie-wrapper .shadow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 20px solid #bdc3c7;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.pie-wrapper.progress-full .pie {
  clip: inherit;
}

.pie-wrapper.progress-full .pie .right-side {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(220deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(220deg);
  transform: rotate(220deg);
}

div,
div:before,
div:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="card radius shadowDepth1">
  <div class="card__content card__padding">
    <article class="card__article">
      <h2><a href="#">Hello world</a></h2>
      <div class="pie-wrapper progress-full">
        <span class="label">2017</span>
        <div class="pie">
          <div class="left-side half-circle"></div>
          <div class="right-side half-circle"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>Bounjour, tout le monde</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```